# YouTube player API live content

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, live-streaming, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to use YouTube player API in my app but I don't know hot to determine if the video is live stream or not. And if anybody knows how to get real duration of the video.

Update:

I figured out a way to determine if content is live or not, I used my backend server for getting the data, but I still can't get the exact duration of the live video.

Comment: Hey did my answer help?  Please feel free to follow up with any questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) `YTPlayerView`, the `playerView:didChangeToQuality:` delegate method will return `kYTPlaybackQualityAuto` for Live Events.

See my pull request on the repo [here](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/pull/56) as well as related discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/pull/55).

The duration of the video should be returned from the `duration` method on the player, but I've found this to be rather unreliable, with some Live Events returning a duration of 0.  Further discussion can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29050771/2415822) Stack Overflow question.

Comment: No, sry but it's javascript api, it has nothing to do with ios.

Answer (score 0):

this is old but you can get the `liveStreamingDetails.actualStartTime` through the youtube API.
With the actualStartTime in hands, you can calculate how much time elapsed.
There is also the endTime in liveStreamingDetails.

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos"
        "?part=liveStreamingDetails"
        "&id=$id&key=$_key"
```