# YouTube Player API live stream duration

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm using YouTube iFrame API for controlling YouTube video in my page. Biggest problem I have is with live streams which I can't get exact duration, but the biggest problem is some kind of a buffer window.

For example I have a stream that is 3h long, but when a user comes in after 3 hours, he can only get the last 2 hours of the video. So first hour of the video is not accessible to the user.

Does anyone knows why? And how can I get that "time window" length? Because in couple of videos that time window was 2h and in some 3h.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current duration of YouTube Live Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050771/get-current-duration-of-youtube-live-event)

Comment: it's not. In that question they are looking for current time.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about what you're asking.  Are you asking for the total length of a live event after the event has ended?  Or the total time while the event is still going on?  Or are you asking why the entire live event is not viewable when joining a few hours in.  Are you using `enableDvr` or archiving?

Comment: I'm looking for the total duration while the stream is still active. When you load the stream for the first time you get a value, but that value does not change over time. And yes, why the entire live event is not viewable after joining in after few hours. Not sure about those 2 options that you are mentioning. It's not my stream, I'm looking at other people live streams.

Comment: @J.D. where you able to solve this?

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta I haven't, but I've stopped trying after a while so not sure what's the state of the API today