# Get YouTube Live Stream total duration

Tags: youtube, live-streaming, youtube-data-api

I want to get the total duration of a current live stream on YouTube (not ended!). This is straightforward for normal videos, e.g.:

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={KEY}

However, for live streams such as [Earth live from ISS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtU_mdL2vBM) this just returns a duration of "PT0S" which essentially means it's 0 seconds long.

There should be a way to get it. One way to get it is via Javascript, if you have the live stream open in your browser:

> ytplayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");
>
> console.log("Duration: " + ytplayer.getDuration());

Is it possible to get from a server-side? [Other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606957/youtube-player-api-live-stream-duration) have asked the same but have not received an answer yet.

Edit: I've just noticed the javascript way of getting the duration doesn't make any sense. For a live stream that started 2 hours ago, getCurrentTime() returns correctly 2*60*60=7200 when at the current time, but getDuration() returns 10245 for whatever reason.